# Is there an automated way to import a GPX file and use the filename as the layer name in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, gpx

I'm using QGIS, importing a lot of GPX files, always selecting the `tracks` layer for each one and clicking OK. The layers end up being named `tracks` by default.

Is there a way to import GPX files (individual or bulk) and automatically use the filename as the layer name instead of having to manually rename the layer each time I import a file?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/aprazdnikov/gistools . Maybe he can give pointers

Comment: Batch GPS Importer (plugin) https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/batch_gps_importer/